# Graphite server doesn't show the new data sent from Java

Tags: java, sockets, monitoring, graphite

I am trying to send plain text data to graphite server with the following code:

```
      try (
            Socket socket = new Socket("companyHost", 2003);
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());) {

        Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        System.out.println(timestamp);

        String sentMessage = "graphite.carbon.local.test.showone 1 " + timestamp;
        System.out.println(sentMessage);
        writer.write(sentMessage);
        writer.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when i check the carbon server under companyHost:port in my web browser, my data isn't there, there is nothing under graphite.carbon.local. Am I missing anything?

My output in the console seems ok (No errors/exceptions):

```
1409233165
graphite.carbon.local.test.showone 1 1409233165
```

I will try to provide more information if necesarry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes I did solve it back in August.

If I recall correctly, all I had to do was to add a new line char "\n" at the end of the message.

As specified in the graphite documentation, the message format is as follows:

```
metric_path value timestamp\n
```

Comment: FYI, here's how I formatted the message `String message = prefix + metricName + " " + metricValue + " " + (long) Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000.0d) + "\n";
`

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples found online - https://www.hostedgraphite.com/docs/languageguide/lg_java.html has a typo.

Timestamp needs to be provided inaddition to metricpath and value as -

```
dos.writeBytes("YOUR-API-KEY.foo 1.2 <timestamp>\n");
```